# Invalid or unexpected token when referencing @odata.count

Tags: postman

I am currently working with an Odata endpoint and am having an issue referencing JSON values with tags including @. The console shows “SyntaxError | Invalid or unexpected token”

[JSON Response Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzzXZ.png)

```js
pm.test("Your test name", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.@odata.count).to.eql(73);
});
```

Can someone explain how I reference that value?

Answer (score 0):

```js
pm.test("Your test name", function() {
  var jsonData = pm.response.json();
  pm.expect(jsonData['@odata.count']).to.eql(73);
});
```